# Summarize regression results on different datasets

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, reporting, application

I have 20 datasets (extracted from 20 different software systems) and fit a logistic regression model on each of them.  On every dataset, the model was the same (same dependent variable and the same set of independent variables).  Now I wonder how to summarize the results.  What I'm currently doing:

1. Determine for each independent variable whether its p-value is below the significance threshold (e.g., p<0.01) and report how many times that was the case.
2. Report the mean, median, and standard deviation of the odds ratios for each independent variable, but only if the variable had a significant effect in the respective dataset.

Is this an acceptable way of summarizing the results of multiple regression models?  Or would you suggest another way?  I've seen the terms "meta-regression analysis" and "hierarchical regression" being used but am unsure whether they apply to my problem.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the nature of these software systems?  In what ways are they similar/different?

Comment: These systems are all written in C and contain conditional compilation directives (`#ifdef` directives).  They differ in their domains (text editors, graphics processing, ...), size (e.g., in terms of lines of code, number of functions, number of files), developers, length of development period, probably coding styles, ...

Comment: I'm not really interested in their specifications, I'm talking about their relation to the outcome.  You say you want to do a logistic regression.  What is the outcome?  Is it is same on all systems?  Would it be reasonable to just concatenate all the data and do one regression?

Comment: Now I get your question!  I am looking at functions.  The independent variables are metrics about how a function is implemented, and the outcome is whether the function is changed (or not) over a certain period of time.  The independent variables and the outcomes are the same in all systems.

Comment: I am hesitant to concatenate the datasets because each system is essentially a different population, with the above-mentioned differences.  Can I just mix them?  Also, the datasets vary greatly in size.  To avoid biases toward the bigger systems, I'd have take equal-sized samples from each one, right?

Comment: I think what you could do is concatenate them and just use a dummy variable to estimate the effect of each implementation.  I can't say more without knowing more about the problem, but from where I stand that seems like a good approach.